# Release Fixed Div at End of Parent Div

Tags: javascript, css, sticky

I have the following code

```
    if ($('body').hasClass('catalog-product-view')) {
        var  scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName("product-img-box")[0];
        var footerx = document.getElementsByClassName("main-footer")[0];
            var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
               html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
         window.alert(scrollTop+','+footerx.offsetTop);
        if (scrollTop > footerx.offsetTop )
        {
            $('.product-img-box').css('position', 'absolute');
        }else
        {
            $('.product-img-box').css('position', 'fixed');
        }
    }
```

I am trying to have the element (el) to change position from fixed to absolute once it touches the footer (footerx). However, I am still getting el overlaps the footer. The question is:
1- I feel I did most calculations of heights, scrolltop and seems my problem is the math to when to switch from fixed to absolute. How am I supposed to do this calculation?
2- What if I want to switch from fixed to absolute at the end of some given ?

The answer of question 1 would be highly appreciated, second question is out of curiosity and great to know.

Comment: What is your desired effect?

Comment: on page load  $('.product-img-box') will be fixed position. Once I scroll down and it touches the footer, then it changes position to absolute.

Comment: Solved it with this condition (if (scrollTop > footerx.offsetTop- window.innerHeight). Now issue appears to be that when switching from absolute to fixed, the left margin changes. You kind of see the image diverges from the edge by some distance as if it was pushed by something. Is this a common behaviour?